# Asp.Net MVC Routing Passing Controller in Url

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I tried to write custom routes.Always i have 404 error what is wrong.I read about routing and did not figure out. I want to display contents like below codes and name must be between a-Z and 0-9.Thanks.

`{action}/{name} /details/kll219dkl`

```
  routes.MapRoute(
             name: "Default",
             url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
              defaults: new { controller = "home", action = "index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
             );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "test",
                url: "details/{name}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Test", action = "Details", name = "ujElk392ow" }
            );
```

and just to showing is working

```
 public ActionResult Details(string name)
 {
    return Content(name);
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "test",
    url: "{controller}/details/{name}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Test", action = "Details", name = String.Empty },
    constraints: new { name = @"^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$" }
);
```

Which would give you:

```
Url:                        Mapped Destination:
/Test/details/kll219dkl     TextController->Details(name: "kll219dkl")
```

Comment: Thanks for reply looks good. when i test controller/action/parameter works but i don't want to display controller name just action/parameter or controller/parameter action always const.

Comment: @Display: Is it always going to be the same controller? If so, remove the `{controller}/` portion from the `url:` parameter and leave the `defaults:`.

Comment: Please Can u write controller/parameter or action/parameter route map i tried still not working.

Comment: assuming `TestController { Details(name) }` just remove `{controller}/` from my answer, then visit `details/kll219dkl`.

Comment: thanks brad, i did give up this issue doesn't work for me and i am using default route map. Maybe future i work on this.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Brad answer. Try to change an order of your routes. Runtime takes first route which fits to request. So routes must be defined from most certain to most general. In your order runtime will always take default route.